# How to stop plotting the graph if data is blank and continue if data is there on the y-axis in base line highcharts

Tags: php, graph, plot, highcharts

I am working on base line highcharts :

How to stop plotting the graph if data is blank and continue if data is there on the y-axis and plot the dates on the x-axis in base line highcharts.

If empty cell is there then the graph itself is auto adjusting : i want to unplot the graph if the cell is empty and continue if the cell is having the value :

This is the code i am fetching the values from the **CSV : with PHP code :**

This is csv File :

```
17-Jul-14   41944
18-Jul-14   18692
19-Jul-14   18692
20-Jul-14   11566
21-Jul-14   10400
22-Jul-14   13355
23-Jul-14   
24-Jul-14   
25-Jul-14   
26-Jul-14   12256
27-Jul-14   13202
28-Jul-14   
29-Jul-14   19458
30-Jul-14   13215
31-Jul-14   14429
1-Aug-14    
2-Aug-14    17166
3-Aug-14    15249
4-Aug-14    15201
5-Aug-14    14911
```

I got the Graph is plotted like this even for the dates :  23-Jul-14    ,24-Jul-14  ,25-Jul-14  ,
28-Jul-14   ,  1-Aug-14  for this dates the values are not there the graph is auto adjusting :

This is image please observe :

Even in the Highcharts Jsfiddle i have tried the graph itself is auto adjusting : if the value is empty :

but i want to unplot the graph where the data is not there

please check this link : **i want required graph :**

http://peltiertech.com/another-approach-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/

in this refrence to union sheet range is the unplotting graph i am trying like this graph,i want this graph as unplotting when the data is not there.

I dont have 10 reputation , that is why i shared the link please check the above link.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>RNA</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    ${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Faluty Trx',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                <?php
                if (($handle = fopen("empty_cells_data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    $i=0;
                    $len = count(file('empty_cells_data.csv'));

                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        if($i==$len - 1){
                            echo "'".$data[0]."'" ;
                        }else{
                            echo "'".$data[0]."'," ;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }
                ?>


                ], labels:{rotation: 65, x:-20}
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'percent'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Faluty TRX',
                data: [

                <?php
                if (($handle = fopen("empty_cells_data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    $i=0;
                    $len = count(file('empty_cells_data.csv'));

                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        if($i==$len - 1){
                            echo $data[1] ;
                        }else{
                            echo $data[1]."," ;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }
                ?>

                ]
            }]
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 660px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried in the with the manual values also by removing the value in the jsfddile which is highcharts link but the graph is plotting auto adjusting :

please help :

thanks in advance :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create graph with gaps, then you should use `null` as value, for example:

```
series: [{
    data: [123, 123, null, null, 123, 321]
}]
```

Then set [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls) to false.

Comment: Thanks , but if the gap is there i want to join the gap without any auto adjusting with x-axis...i mean covering the gap with line or red line ..is there any possible way...can you please help..!!

Comment: Then set connectNulls to true. However it would be exactly the same color. As another solution, you can try to use [multicolor_series](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series) plugin. Or just use separate series to put there a line with disabled tooltip.

Comment: This option will coloring entire line , but i want to color that gap filled line only...

Comment: can you please help , i have one doubt that if i click on the series it will hide the graph and again if i click show the graph than it is displaying on the right side of the graph, i want to display if on below the graph..

Comment: that is class="highcharts-legend"  , i want display this as down the graph

Comment: To connect two separate series use `linkedTo` option - then you will get only one series for two lines in the legend.

Comment: Hi @pawel , can you please help with one more question .

Comment: I am using the bar graph - basic column , i want to put perticular bar as a red color and the remaining as the blue...how can i do that..?

Comment: Sure, then that point should be an object, like this: `data: [123, 123, {y: 123, color: 'red'}]`.

Comment: Actually i took in loop...doing in php...done in while loop fetching data from the csv file .. now for a particular bar i want to put the color:'red'..                                         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
             
               if($i==$len - 1){
                echo $data[2] ;
                }else{
                echo $data[2]."," ;
                }
              $i++;
             }

Comment: Sorry, I'm not PHP guru.. :)